# Cannot create Moq test with Interface while making the function virtual works

Tags: c#, integration-testing, moq

I'm trying to test this class:

```
public class Tasks : ITaskEnumerableProvider
{
    protected string ConnectionString;
    DAL_EFCore.AdventureWorks2017Context CurrentContext;
    public Tasks(DAL_EFCore.AdventureWorks2017Context currentContext)
    {
        CurrentContext = currentContext;
    }
    public Tasks(string connectionString)
    {
        ConnectionString = connectionString;            
    }
    public DAL_EFCore.AdventureWorks2017Context GetContext()
    {
        if (CurrentContext != null)
            return CurrentContext;
        else
        {
            var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddDbContextPool<DAL_EFCore.AdventureWorks2017Context>
                (
                options => options.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString)
                );
            var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
            CurrentContext = serviceProvider.GetService<DAL_EFCore.AdventureWorks2017Context>();
            return CurrentContext;
        }
    }
    public IEnumerable<SalesOrderMinMaxTotalDuePerTerritoryForMarketingOrders> SalesOrderMinMaxTotalDuePerTerritoryForMarketingOrders()
    {
        return GetContext().Employee
            .GroupBy(e => e.Gender)
            .Select(n => new SalesOrderMinMaxTotalDuePerTerritoryForMarketingOrders
            {
                Gender = n.Key,
                Count = n.Count()
            })
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

And this one:

```
public class DataReports : IDataReports
{
    protected ITaskEnumerableProvider TaskProvider;
    protected string ConnectionString;
    protected string DalModeSelected;
    public DataReports() {}
    public DataReports(DBConfig config)
    {
        ConnectionString = config.ConnectionString;
        DalModeSelected = config.DAL;
    }
    public ITaskEnumerableProvider GetTaskProvider()
    {
        switch (DalModeSelected)
        {
            case "ADO":
                return new ADOTaskProvider.Tasks(ConnectionString);
            case "EFCore":
                return new EFCoreTaskProvider.Tasks(ConnectionString);
            default:
                throw new FormatException("The format of the variable which represend the selected DAL was not correct");
        }
    } 
    public IEnumerable<SalesOrderMinMaxTotalDuePerTerritoryForMarketingOrders> SalesOrderMinMaxTotalDuePerTerritoryForMarketingOrders()
    {
        return GetTaskProvider().SalesOrderMinMaxTotalDuePerTerritoryForMarketingOrders().ToList();
    }
```

I'm testing with this code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void SalesOrderMinMaxTotalDuePerTerritoryForMarketingOrdersTest()
{
    // Setup Mock Data and context
    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DAL_EFCore.AdventureWorks2017Context>()
        .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "SalesOrderMinMaxTotalDuePerTerritoryForMarketingOrdersTest")
        .Options;
    using (var context = new DAL_EFCore.AdventureWorks2017Context(options))
    {
        InsertData(options);
    }
    using (var context = new DAL_EFCore.AdventureWorks2017Context(options))
    {
        // Mock EFCoreTaskProvider.Tasks
        var mockEFCoreTaskProvider = new Mock<EFCoreTaskProvider.Tasks>(ConnectionString);
        mockEFCoreTaskProvider.As<IGetContext>();
        mockEFCoreTaskProvider.CallBase = true;
        mockEFCoreTaskProvider.Setup(x => x.GetContext()).Returns(context);

        // Mock CoreReportService.DataReports
        var config = new DBConfig { DAL = "EFCore", ConnectionString = ConnectionString };
        var mockDataReports = new Mock<DataReports>(config).As<IDataReports>();
        mockDataReports.CallBase = true;
        mockDataReports.Setup(x => x.GetTaskProvider()).Returns(mockEFCoreTaskProvider.Object);

        var test = mockDataReports.Object.SalesOrderMinMaxTotalDuePerTerritoryForMarketingOrders().ToList();
        Assert.IsTrue(test.Count == 1);
    }
}
```

I'm using an inmemorydatabase to test the data but the `test.Count` of the TestCase has the count that corresponds from the real database.

If I make `GetContext()` and `GetTaskProvider()` *virtual* I'm getting the correct `Count` from the virtual database but I don't want them to be virtual, I also prefer if they were not public, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a matter of design.

> what am i doing wrong?

`DataReports` is tightly coupled to implementation concerns and is also violating Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) and Separation of Concerns (SoC).

By having `DataReports` create the providers, it is tightly coupled to them, and prevents you from being able to replace them when testing.

Abstract the provider creation out into its own concern

For example

```
//Abstraction
public interface ITaskProviderFactory {
    ITaskEnumerableProvider GetTaskProvider();
}

//Implementation
public class DefaultTaskProviderFactory : ITaskProviderFactory{
    private readonly DBConfig config;

    public DefaultTaskProviderFactory(DBConfig config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    public ITaskEnumerableProvider GetTaskProvider() {
        switch (config.DAL) {
            case "ADO":
                return new ADOTaskProvider.Tasks(config.ConnectionString);
            case "EFCore":
                return new EFCoreTaskProvider.Tasks(config.ConnectionString);
            default:
                throw new FormatException("The format of the variable which represent the selected DAL was not correct");
        }
    }
}
```

And refactor the `DataReports` accordingly

```
public class DataReports : IDataReports {
    private readonly ITaskProviderFactory factory;

    public DataReports(ITaskProviderFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    private ITaskEnumerableProvider getTaskProvider() {
        return factory.GetTaskProvider();
    } 

    public IEnumerable<SalesOrderMinMaxTotalDuePerTerritoryForMarketingOrders> SalesOrderMinMaxTotalDuePerTerritoryForMarketingOrders() {
        return getTaskProvider().SalesOrderMinMaxTotalDuePerTerritoryForMarketingOrders().ToList();
    }
}
```

At run-time in production, the appropriate implementation can be explicitly injected.

For an integration test of `DataReports` the actual implementations can be swapped out as needed in order to verify the expected behavior.

For example

```
[TestMethod]
public void SalesOrderMinMaxTotalDuePerTerritoryForMarketingOrdersTest() {
    //Arrange
    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DAL_EFCore.AdventureWorks2017Context>()
        .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "SalesOrderMinMaxTotalDuePerTerritoryForMarketingOrdersTest")
        .Options;

    using (var context = new DAL_EFCore.AdventureWorks2017Context(options)) {
        InsertData(options);
    }

    using (var context = new DAL_EFCore.AdventureWorks2017Context(options)) {
        //actual EFCoreTaskProvider.Tasks targeting in-memory database
        var taskProvider = new EFCoreTaskProvider.Tasks(context);

        //mock factory configured to return the desired provider
        var mockFactory = Mock.Of<ITaskProviderFactory>(_ =>
            _.GetTaskProvider() == taskProvider //return the actual provider for testing
        );

        // actual CoreReportService.DataReports (Subject under test)
        var dataReports = DataReports(mockFactory);

        //Act
        var result = dataReports.SalesOrderMinMaxTotalDuePerTerritoryForMarketingOrders().ToList();

        //Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(result.Count == 1);
    }
}
```

The original design of your classes is not very flexible so it makes it difficult to isolate parts for testing.

Comment: wow i'm having a hard time to understand why it is better, i will read it may times

Comment: @CDrosos in your approach there was no way for you to intercept the creation of the providers without exposing the functions publicly and trying to mock the subject under test. With this approach only the necessary dependencies need to be mocked and injected into the subject under test.

Comment: @CDrosos this also follows a more closely to SOLID principles.

Comment: you have change so little but has made so big difference. in general the method that i wasn't able to access unless i make it virtual(GetTaskProvider()), you made it to another class public and with its own interface, and so it could be mocked?

Comment: @CDrosos Being able to mock it is a beneficial side effect. Moving it into its own class was done to separate concerns/responsibility of the classes. the interface was to allow for better dependency inversion and because classes should depend on abstractions and not concretions.